# VBA find number with decimal between two numbers

Tags: excel, vba

In the screenshot you can see some part of my table.

[image]

In columns A:D I put in some Value, the Value in Column B is searched in Row 1 and the Value from C:D is search in Row 2. After that it colors the cells red which are in the founded range.

The Examples "Test" and "Test2" works fine. But the 3. and 4. example does not work with my code, because the given numbers are not in Range("E2:AM2").

My question now, is how can i find the Start- and Endtemp if there are numbers like 5,15,25,152,87, ...

**Here is my Code so far:**

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim a As Long
    Dim turnCol As Range

    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    With ws
        If Not Application.Intersect(Range("D:D"), Range(Target.Address)) Is Nothing Then
            a = ActiveCell.Row

            Turns = "Turn " & .Cells(a, 2).Value
            StartTemp = Int(CDec(.Cells(a, 3).Value))
            EndTemp = Int(CDec(.Cells(a, 4).Value))

            Set turnCol = .Range("1:1").Find(What:=Turns)
            Set startCol = .Range(.Cells(2, turnCol.Column), .Cells(2, turnCol.Column + 35)).Find(What:=StartTemp)
            Set endCol = .Range(.Cells(2, turnCol.Column), .Cells(2, turnCol.Column + 35)).Find(What:=EndTemp)

            .Range(.Cells(a, startCol.Column), .Cells(a, endCol.Column)).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
        End If
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Use `Application.Match()` to locate the columns.  Don't forget you also need to clear any previous shading if someone changes an existing value.  Or use (eg) `StartTemp = Application.Floor(.Cells(a, 3).Value, 10)` to round down to the nearest 10 and continue to use `Find()`

Comment: thanks for the fast answer, but i´m not really familiar with `Application.Match()` .. in which line do i have to add it?

Comment: You might find it easier to use my other suggestion of just rounding the inputs to the nearest 10.

Comment: Thanks, the second suggestion works fine for me .. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 0):

Currently there's a difference between Excel sheets, having macros enabled and having macros disabled. In order to have something which works on every Excel file, I'd advise you to avoid macros, unless really needed.

In this specific case, macros are not needed indeed: you can solve your issue using conditional formatting:

- Conditional formatting

  - Highlighting rules
  - Between:

    - =$C$2
    - =$D$2
    - Custom format (Fill with red colour)

Good luck